# Unicode and Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, unicode, android-ndk, icu

Is there any way to use UTF-8/16 strings in the NDK without including a multi-megabyte library such as ICU? Is ICU built in to Android?

Comment: ICU is used in Android, but i do not know if there is any way to access it. It would be nice. I'm using own code for encoding and decoding UTF8 in NDK.

Comment: I think [`libiconv`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) is a possible alternative if you find the licensing agreeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ICU is only multimegabyte if you go with a default build including [all this](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/files.html), hundreds of codepages and several hundred locales worth of data.

Have a look at ["Making ICU Smaller"](http://userguide.icu-project.org/packaging#TOC-Making-ICU-Smaller). I just added a note about using static builds.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for fixing the link. If anyone is following along, ICU 49 will have drastically improved support for static builds depending on which functions are used.

Answer (score 4):

`std::string` is capable of storing UTF-8 directly. You will need special libraries, like ICU, only if you want to parse strings in some way. For a simple output without parsing, just go with `std::string` and forget about all those libraries.

Comment: That's a good point, +1. But I can't help but feel he wants to do something with them rather than pass them between systems that can process them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something smaller than ICU, check [UTF8-CPP library](https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp).

Comment: How much overhead (size) does this add to my project? ICU is around 9MB, which is just way too much.

Comment: I just checked it out. It doesn't do anything I need. It doesn't convert between codepages and UTF.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative lib: [Iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/)

Size: about 900kb (which is smaller in APK)